# ajax call not working in external js file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a Registration page having only UserName and Password field. I want to submit new User Details on Click event of Submit button. PLease tell me how do I use ajax call using jquery. I have defined Insert function on button click in ASP.net. But it's not working.

```
function Insert() {
    alert("Insert");

    var uname = $('#txtRUserName').val();

    alert(uname)
    var password = $('#txtRPassword').val();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "login.aspx/Insert",
            data: "{'uname:'" + uname + ",'password:'" + password + "}",
            datatype: "text/html",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            contentType: "text/html",
            success: function processData(r) {
                var myItem = r.d.split('#');
                alert(myItem)
            }
            //error: errorAlert
        });
    alert("jqajax")
}
```

Comment: What part is not working, do you get any off your errors. What are you expecting to happen ? Is the form still meant to post or just run the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Valid json, ContentType and DataType**

You could change your call to be valid json i.e.

```
data: "{uname:'" + uname + "',password:'" + password + "'}",
```

Your content type needs to be:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

And your data type needs to be:

```
dataType: "json"
```

So your javascript would become:

```
function Insert() {
    alert("Insert");

    var uname = $('#txtRUserName').val();

    alert(uname)
    var password = $('#txtRPassword').val();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "login.aspx/Insert",
            data: "{uname:'" + uname + "',password:'" + password + "'}",
            datatype: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function processData(r) {
                var myItem = r.d.split('#');
                alert(myItem)
            }
            //error: errorAlert
        });
    alert("jqajax")
}
```

**EnablePageMethods**

You need to enable page methods in your script manager like so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

**Page behind code**

You also need to make sure that your method has the `[WebMethod]` attribute and is also static i.e. something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Insert(string uname, string password)
```

Comment: jQuery does this automatically.

Comment: actually retract that.. i just saw the data is wrapped in quotes for some reason.

Comment: For my own info... can Page methods be executed from the URL?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Yes, sure.

Comment: The data being sent is not JSON, even if it looks similar to it. The keys are quoted with the wrong characters and the values are not quoted at all.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Very handy in web forms if you just want to quickly implement an ajax function that is only used in one place without having to knock-up a webservice for it. :)

Comment: @Quentin Yes, you are right. I've put quotes in my test app. :) Will update my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Tty this when posting a form the  `$(this).serializeArray();` takes care of the input data

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function( e ) {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
               datatype: "text/html",
               cache: false,
               async: false,
               contentType: "text/html",
                type: 'post',
                url: 'page.php',
                data: postData,
                success: function () {
                  var myItem = r.d.split('#');
                  alert(myItem)
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

EDIT:
change the  $('form') To the form id.